# How to validate these 2 fields with different error messages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 fields: Name Query and Company ID. They need to satisfy the following conditions:

1. Form can be submitted when 1 of these 2 fields is valid, i.e. not empty, and "Please fill in ..." message is shown
2. Both fields are validated on key up and focus out
3. For company Id field, it checks with regex on key up and focus out, if not valid, form cannot be submitted, and showing message "Invalid company ID format"

Here is my solution:

```js
var myForm = $("#myForm");

$.validator.addMethod("regx", function (value, element, regexpr) {
            return regexpr.test(value);
        }, function (params, element) {
            return "Invalid company ID format"
        });

myForm.validate({
  rules: {
    nameQuery: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
    },
    companyId: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
      regx: /^$|^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d\d\/\d\/\w\w\w\w+$/
    }
  },
  messages: {
    nameQuery: {
      required: "Please fill in name query"
    },
    companyId: {
      required: "Please fill in company ID"
    }
  },
  errorClass: "alert",
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
  },
  onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
  },
  highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    $("p").html('Form submitted')
  },
  invalidHandler: function (form) {
    $("p").empty();
  }
})
```

```css
input.alert {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label.alert {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <label for="nameQuery">Name Query: </label>
  <input class="mygroup" id="nameQuery" name="nameQuery">
  </br>
  <label for="companyId">Company Id: </label>
  <input class="mygroup" id="companyId" name="companyId">
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <p></p>
</form>
```

Other stuff working well, but the customised messages when empty seem not working, the default messages "Please fill at least 1 of these fields" are showing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to set `required` to all fields mb `require_from_group` is not enough in your case?

Comment: @Egor S. Yes I did tried, and this results in all fields need to be validated rather than 1 out of 2 fields.

Comment: If you want custom messages on `require_from_group`, then set custom messages on `require_from_group`, not on `required` as you have done.  Have you reviewed [the documentation for this plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) as I suggested in my answer on your last question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... default messages "Please fill at least 1 of these fields" are showing. Any suggestions?"*

It's showing the default messages for `require_from_group` because you have not defined any custom message for this rule/method.

Instead you're setting a custom message on the `required` rule/method, which is a rule you're not even using.

A custom message for a rule/method must correspond to the name of that rule/method, which is called `require_from_group` in this case.

```
// messages object/option
messages: {  
    // name attribute of the field
    nameQuery: {
        // name of the rule/method being used
        require_from_group: "Please fill in name query"
    },
    companyId: {
        require_from_group: "Please fill in company ID"
    } ....
```

---

**Note**:  In your custom method, you do not need a function to return the message unless you're dynamically changing that message.  Instead, you can just specify a string as the message in place of a function.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    // name
    "regx",
    // method
    function (value, element, regexpr) {
        return regexpr.test(value);
    },
    // message
    "Invalid company ID format"  // just the string in this case
);
```

Additionally, you didn't even need to write a custom method for Regex since the Additional Methods file already contains a rule called `pattern` that will do this.

```
....
companyId: {
    require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
    pattern: '^$|^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d\d\/\d\/\w\w\w\w+$'
....
```

Finally, whatever you do with `highlight` should be reversed with `unhighlight`.

```
....
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
}, ....
```

You also might want to consider updating the version of jQuery Validate as v1.12.0 is more than five years old (April 2014) at this point.

---

**DEMO**:

```js
var myForm = $("#myForm");

myForm.validate({
  rules: {
    nameQuery: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
    },
    companyId: {
      require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
      pattern: '^$|^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]\d\d\d\/\d\/\w\w\w\w+$'
    }
  },
  messages: {
    nameQuery: {
      require_from_group: "Please fill in name query"
    },
    companyId: {
      require_from_group: "Please fill in company ID",
      pattern: "Invalid company ID format"
    }
  },
  errorClass: "alert",
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
  },
  onfocusout: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
  },
  highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    $("p").html('Form submitted')
  },
  invalidHandler: function (form) {
    $("p").empty();
  }
})
```

```css
input.alert {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
label.alert {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
  <label for="nameQuery">Name Query: </label>
  <input class="mygroup" id="nameQuery" name="nameQuery">
  </br>
  <label for="companyId">Company Id: </label>
  <input class="mygroup" id="companyId" name="companyId">
  </br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <p></p>
</form>
```